# uGet Message: No response. Is aria2 shutdown?

Tags: google-chrome, uget

I have the following configurations:

1. Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit
2. Chrome 70 64 bit
3. uGet Integration plugin 2.1.3

When I try to download any file, I get the following error message:

> Message: No response. Is aria2 shutdown?

I have no any idea about the cause or the solution of that issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have just found the solution which depends on canceling aria2, indeed, I don't know what is aria2 or what is its functionality!

- Open uGet settings
- From plugin section
- In Plugin Matching Order list, select curl.

Checkout the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Both `curl` and `aria2` are download utilities. Both aren't part of the standard install. It's possible that something you installed pulled in `curl` and so your plugin now works fine. If you install the `aria2` package from the `universe` repo, your plugin would probably see that as well. I use `curl` for some purposes, and `aria2` for others.

Comment: @DKBose However, curl, probably, is installed by default in most Linux distros. Let we agree that restricting the option exclusively to curl could be a quick fix

Comment: Besides Kubuntu, I just checked 18.04 versions of Lubuntu, Ubuntu, and Xubuntu. None of them have `curl` installed by default.

Comment: @DKBose, You may be right because I'm developer, so I may install it randomly with some dependencies for PHP.